# Single Responsibility Principle vs. Move Method Refactoring

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring, single-responsibility-principle

I seem to be caught between two design guidelines.

I have a class that represents a three-dimensional volume, that is made of blocks. This class provides simple modification methods, such as *AddBlock* or *RemoveBlock*.

There are several things I need to do with this class

First, i need to know certain aggregate properties about the volume, with methods such as *GetTotalWeight* or *GetMaximumWidth*.

Second, i need to perform transformation operations over this volumes, such as *Shrink* or *Trim*, which do pretty much what the names tell you (no need to go into detail, volumes just change according to some rules, by adding or removing blocks). These operations have lots of logic in them.

My question is: If I add these query and transformation methods to the *Volume* class, does this break the **single responsibility principle**?
My classes responsibilities would be:

- Hold the volume data, allowing simple modifications (add and remove blocks)
- Provide aggregate information about the volume
- Provide transform capabilities for these volumes.

If I decide this is too much responsibility, and that the *Volume* class should just represent the volume, I would need to create classes such as *VolumeTrimmer*, *VolumeShrinker*, and so on, for the transformations, and *WeightCalculator* for the queries

This last option seems to neatly separate the concerns in different classes. However, if I look at the details of the *Trim(Volume v)* of my *VolumeTrimmer*, all it does is call operations over volume. At the same time, the *CalculateWeight(Volume v)* method of my *WeightCalculator* seems to be mostly concerned with *Volume*.

When I look at this kind of method, I feel compelled to use the **Move Method** refactoring. I look at the code and say 'this method is mostly concerned with the properties of another class, therefore i better move this method to this class'. But this brings the responsibility back to the *Volume* class!

Any ideas on how should I approach this problem? Am I understanding these guidelines wrong?

Comment: A `Volume` class seems weird to me. Volume is a property of something, like a structure.

Comment: @Sam: he means "a volume", meaning "a three dimensional region of space"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual the one and only correct answer to this kind of question is: it depends.

It often makes sense to have classes that are simple data containers, like your volume class, without the methods for shrinking, trimming and so on.

There is also the option to have Trimmer and Shrinker only be used inside the Volume class. This way you have the Volume and its operations nicely wrapped up in a single class, but also have the complex methods separated, which might for example help with testing.

So how to decide which is the right design? Here are a couple of guiding questions:

1. For the Shrinker and so on, do you need to make stuff public in the Volume class that otherwise would be private? If so this hints towards methods Of Volume
2. Are there alternative implementation imaginable for Shrinker&Co, possibly for testing purposes or with different performance characteristics? If so this hints toward separate classes.
3. Does a client of Volume most of the time use the add/removeBlock mehtods AND the shrink AND the trim method? This would hint toward a single class again.
4. Does Shrinker&Co each only need a subset of the API of Volume? If so this hints toward separate classes.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer. I thought the answer would be a big 'depends', but I needed to make sure. I'll keep your examples in mind while moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the single responsibility principle is pretty arbitrary, as no piece of code from a higher level language can do only one thing.
That being said, it seems your VolumeTrimmer and VolumeShrinker are interested in only **subsets** of Volume's properties. Therefore it makes sense to segregate those classes and give them only the subset of properties that they are interested in. This makes them reusable in other scenarios where another class also has this subset and desires the same behavior, but doesn't need to know anything about Volume.
Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with this. This seems to be an example of the [*Composite* pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). Your volume is composed of blocks.

There's no reason that your volume can't have volume-wide operations, like Transform, which may be implemented by delegation to block-level Transform operations.